# jquery how to check if string contains specific numeric value

Tags: jquery

How can I check with a jQuery if string value contains the specified numeric value?
For e.g;

```
a= 13
c = 12

b = 'we have 13 monkeys in the Zoo"
```

how to check if `( a in b = True)`  and `(c in b = False)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex to achieve that :

```js
var a = 13,
    c = 12,
    b = 'we have 13 monkeys in the Zoo';
    
if (b.match('\\b' + a + '\\b')) {
  console.log('b includes a');
}

if (b.match('\\b' + c + '\\b')) {
  console.log('b includes c');
}
```

Using `\b` limit search to match the whole word, here "13", addressing the issue pointed out by George.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
var s = $.grep(b.split(' '), function(v) {
  return v == a
});

if (s.length) {
  console.log('b includes a');
}
```

**Demo**

```js
var a = 13,
  c = 12,
  b = 'we have 13 monkeys in the Zoo';
d = 'we have 134 monkeys in the Zoo';

var s = $.grep(b.split(' '), function(v) {
  return v == a
});

var t = $.grep(d.split(' '), function(v) {
  return v == a
});

if (s.length) {
  console.log('b includes a');
}
if (t.length) {
  console.log('d includes a');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```